# MS Office last updates causing some strange behavior in handling VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-automation

Our admins ran some MS Office 2016 updates (Build 11929.20838) and all of a sudden I noticed a few unexpected errors in one of my previously written Excel VBA macros. For example below error is popping up against any variable which I have not defined explicitly. It was not the case before and unless I had mentioned Option Explicit, I had never experienced anything like this.

Compile error:
Can't find project or library

I am also getting the same error against the following 2 statements of my code, whereas it used to run smoothly before the last Microsoft Office 2016 update.

```
' Against the following two declarations, the compiler is highlighting  
' Date in parenthesis and quoting same error "Can't find project or library"

xMonth = VBA.DateTime.Month(Date)
xYear = VBA.DateTime.Year(Date)

' And showing same error as above against defining an Array variable like below
srchString = Array("invoice_number", "invoice_date", "Category_wise_code", "Bill To Customer", "consignees_address_long")

'And even here, it is giving the same error:
[A1].Font.Bold = True
```

Does anyone have any idea about these errors and how to resolve this issue? All of this quite unexpected. Let me tell you this macro has been in my use for over 4 years and I never ran into issues like these.

You will find something fishy here:
https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHZL_enGB838GB838&ei=EOInX-ibPMeusAXFw7z4Cg&q=%22ms+office+2016%22+%22july+updates%22+%22VBA%22&oq=%22ms+office+2016%22+%22july+updates%22+%22VBA%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQRzoICCEQFhAdEB46BQghEKABUOTJCljq_gtgg4UMaABwAXgAgAHzAogByiiSAQYyLTIuMTSYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjo4_6J5f7qAhVHF6wKHcUhD68Q4dUDCAw&uact=5

Although not all links are opening, but Google window is briefly showing that some people are also facing macro crash situation.

Thanks for your time reading my post.

Comment: Have you done a repair on your office installation, if not try.

Comment: Try looking to References (in VBE - Tools -> References...) and see if you have a 'Missing' one (or more). If yes, try to make a proper one(s), or un-check it/them and see what is to be done when you will need it/them (if it will be the case).

Comment: Always use `Option Explicit` and declare all of your variables. Does it still happen?